# Square root of a negative number pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor (on cuda device) filled with negative and positive numbers and i want to compute the square root of this tensor. I would like the output to be a ComplexFloatTensor (since sqrt(-1)=i). How can i do that in pytorch please ?

I found a solution by doing `np.emath.sqrt(x.cpu().numpy())` but i am looking for a solution which doesn't use the cpu, only the gpu.

Comment: Extremely nerdy technical note: `i` is not equal to `sqrt(-1)`. Instead, `i²` equals `-1`. And those might feel like the same thing, but one of those can be geometrically illustrated through rotation in the complex plane, while the other cannot.

Comment: Yes i know, it was just to simplify and to make my point understandable ^^

Comment: Not everyone reading this post will though =D

Comment: You're right, i should have be more precise, thanks

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans `i` isn't *defined* as the square root of -1, but for a suitably defined, complex-valued extension of the square-root function, `sqrt(-1) == i` is certainly a true equation.

Answer (score 1):

just convert to complex before calling `sqrt`

```
In [26]: t = torch.tensor([1,2,3,-1,-2,-3], dtype=torch.float)

In [27]: torch.sqrt(t)
Out[27]: tensor([1.0000, 1.4142, 1.7321,    nan,    nan,    nan])

In [28]: torch.sqrt(t.to(torch.complex64))
Out[28]:
tensor([1.0000+0.0000j, 1.4142+0.0000j, 1.7321+0.0000j, 0.0000+1.0000j,
        0.0000+1.4142j, 0.0000+1.7321j])
```